How can I grant read permission for HTTPS certificates?
I'm enabling Gitea HTTPS access.
On my server I got certificates using Certbot.
The certificates are installed into:
Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem
Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/privkey.pem

and here their default permissions:
$ ls -lh /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/*.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 May  5 11:34 /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/cert.pem -> ../../archive/mydomain/cert1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 May  5 11:34 /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/chain.pem -> ../../archive/mydomain/chain1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 May  5 11:34 /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/mydomain/fullchain1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 May  5 11:34 /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/privkey.pem -> ../../archive/mydomain/privkey1.pem

here the actual files:
$ ls -lh /etc/letsencrypt/archive/mydomain/*.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.5K May  5 11:34 /etc/letsencrypt/archive/mydomain/cert1.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.8K May  5 11:34 /etc/letsencrypt/archive/mydomain/chain1.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.3K May  5 11:34 /etc/letsencrypt/archive/mydomain/fullchain1.pem
-rw------- 1 root root  241 May  5 11:34 /etc/letsencrypt/archive/mydomain/privkey1.pem

$ ls -lh /etc/letsencrypt/archive/
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K May  5 11:34 mydomain

$ ls -lh /etc/letsencrypt/
total 28K
drwx------ 3 root root 4.0K May  5 11:11 accounts
drwx------ 3 root root 4.0K May  5 11:34 archive
drwx------ 3 root root 4.0K May  5 11:34 live
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  774 May  5 11:11 options-ssl-nginx.conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K May  5 11:34 renewal
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4.0K May  5 11:11 renewal-hooks
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  424 May  5 11:11 ssl-dhparams.pem

They seem all readable from other users, even the parent directories until live that is readable only by root.
When I run Gitea service I get the following error:
May 05 11:47:53 vps gitea[511691]: 2024/05/05 11:47:53 cmd/web_https.go:170:runHTTPS() [E] Failed to load https cert file /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem for tcp:0.0.0>
May 05 11:47:53 vps gitea[511691]: 2024/05/05 11:47:53 cmd/web.go:353:listen() [E] Failed to start server: open /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem: permission denied

Gitea has its own user gitea.
How to allow it to read the certificates?
I'm concerned of just making the directory 755.

The files inside live are symlinks. the actual files are the ones inside the archive path.
Normally, the private key inside the archive is owner-readable. To solve this issue, simply execute below command:
chown gitea:gitea -R /etc/letsencrypt/archive/yourdomain/
Another dirty solution is running Gitea using root user on systemd which I do not suggest.

Ok, I was able to do this but I thought it would be a security leak

It is not! Since the Gitea service wants to read the file, and you defined that the owner of this file is Gitea user, there are no other users who can read the file.

Got it. Last question, this would prevent me to use the same certificate for other services, like nginx, right? Is there a way to allow multiple services (and then users) to use the same certificate?

You can define a user, for example, www-data, and configure both Nginx and Gitea to be run by this user, you can change it in your systemd unit file.
